# Can't login to codeplex TFS via Visual studio 10

Tags: visual-studio, codeplex

I use codeplex.com to host my projects. Some days ago I connect to codeplex successful via visual studio ultimate 10 but now I can't. 
Could you help me please? Below is the screen shot of the message I received from codeplex.

PS. You could see my discussion in CodePlex Information and Discussion here: http://codeplex.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=240384

[image]

Thanks.
Binh Nguyen

Comment: Yeah, me too! An issue has been raised on their own site but things remain silience http://codeplex.codeplex.com/workitem/25603 !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now codeplex runs again. Sometime it deads, sometime not.

SO BAD!